# How do I include string value and image file in ajax request to backend?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to send an image along with some input text values using jquery ajax

I tried sending only the image and everything seems to work..
but when I include the the input with text values this shows up 
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.`

```
            var file_data = $('#picture').prop('files')[0];   
            var form_data = new FormData();   
            form_data.append('image', file_data);
            form_data.append(
                    'firstname'   ,   about[0],
                    'middlename'  ,   about[1],
                    'lastname'    ,   about[2],
                    'email'       ,   about[3],
                    'number'      ,   about[4],
                    'username'    ,   account[0],
                    'password'    ,   account[1],
                    'rfid'        ,   account[2],
                    'type'        ,   account[3],
                    'status'      ,   account[4],
            ); 
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: baseurl+"/admin/test",
                data: form_data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                dataType: "json",
                failure : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error" + textStatus);
                },
```

Please tell me how to do this right..

Comment: You will have to append each parameter separately not in one single call to append.. See for specs of formData.append  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send your request with `Content-type: multipart/form-data` and note that you can only append one key and value in each formData.append()

PS: using camelCase variable is the best practice for JS :-)

```
const formData = new FormData()
const fileData = $('#picture').prop('files')[0]
formData.append('image', fileData)
formData.append('firstname', about[0])
/* add the rest of your data */
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: baseurl + "/admin/test",
    config
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this kind of code, you can simply do it like this...
Let me clearify to you, You have a `<form enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>` and in this form you have all the inputs that you have appended, and you will also have a submit button right ? So, give all your inputs a name and give a class to your submit button, like this `<button class="sendData" type="submit">Submit</button>` and you will have `mulitpart/form-data` in form tag as you see above, this is for images or files...

Next thing is to use it in jquery...

```
$(document).on('click','.sendData',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var form_data = new FormData(this.form);
  $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: baseurl+"/admin/test",
            data: form_data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            failure : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("error" + textStatus);
            },
});
```

This will give you everything you want. You don't need the extra code, just `dd();` the data in your php code and see all the data. I hope it may help you.